# ruby test if a subdomain belongs to a domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns

is it possible in rails to check if a subdomain belongs to a domain?
Example:

```
blog.example.com belongs to example.com ? yes
blog.foo.com belongs to example.com? no
example.com belongs to example.com? yes
```

I need a deep test, not only a string-like test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the relationship is simply to determine whether a subdomain is part of another domain (and you know both the subdomain and the domain) then the match is a simple comparison.

```
s1 = 'blog.example.com'
s2 = 'blog.foo.com'
s3 = 'example.com'
s4 = 'blog.counterexample.com'

d = 'example.com'

s1.end_with?(".#{d}") || s1 == d
# => true
s2.end_with?(".#{d}") || s2 == d
# => false
s3.end_with?(".#{d}") || s3 == d
# => true
s4.end_with?(".#{d}") || s4 == d
# => false
```

Otherwise, if you need to decompose a subdomain into the domain, then you need something more elaborate. In this case I encourage you to use the Public Suffix List, you can use the [Public Suffix gem](http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/publicsuffix).

```
domain = PublicSuffix.parse("google.com")
# => #

domain.tld
# => "com"
domain.sld
# => "google"
domain.trd
# => nil

domain.domain
# => "google.com"
domain.subdomain
# => nil
```

As a side note, the language behind Rails is Ruby and this is a Ruby problem, not really a Rails problem.

Comment: PublicSuffix i think is for me. i want to parse the http response find the origin domain/subdomain and test if the origin domain/subdomain belongs to a Prefixed_Domain harded in the ruby code.